# Why can I use QSerialPort* as a temporary variable but not as a class' member in Qt 5.5.1?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qt5

I was trying to build a GUI for a project with an [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Introduction). The project itself is about a car-robot for harbor's containers management, and during the time it's on the development stage (and also on final release) would be cool to have a way to monitor and send commands to it. 
 Seems a good idea to initially implement a communication via serial port and then rewrite/reuse the code for a radio communicator or something like that. The code was going well until *some bugs come up*.

First  were used `QSerialPort` and `QSerialPortInfo`,  following  the example of [several programs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-examples.html) available at Qt's website. The compiler showed up with  some errors about a missing `"QT+=serialport"` and about wrong forward declarations but after a while I could fix them. Then when the code to open a serial port was written, *the program started to crash...*

After some hours, this GUI Qt code (and a respective console version) works and exemplifies the problem:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QtSerialPort/qserialport.h>
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSerialPort *connected_port;
    connected_port = new QSerialPort;

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

 class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

However just after changing **mainwindow.h** and inserting `QSerialPort *connected_port;` in MainWindows's `private` section and removing it from **mainwindow.cpp**, this simple program starts to crash.

**mainwindow.h**

```
  (...)

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {

  (...)

    private:
        QSerialPort *connected_port;
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

  (...)
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
  (...)

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

    ui->setupUi(this);

    connected_port = new QSerialPort;

}

  (...)
```

Will crash. In qt's terminal example is a similar approach, but I did not get the why it works and this code don't. How make it work?

Comment: I do not see why this would not work, I do the same in some applications. Perhaps try calling the constructor as: ... = new QSerialPort("myport");

Comment: @TheBadger That's a good idea, but it didn't work (neither the constructor with QSerialPortInfo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. For some reason, adding a `"QT+=widgets"` on the .pro file produced a functional program, aside the  already added `"QT+=serialport"`.

Comment: FYI: You do not need `"QT+=widgets"` for using Serial Ports in Qt. I run applications with serial ports all the time - I don't always use GUI components so I don't need widgets. I would say you must have been having a gui/widgets issue, not a serial port issue.

Comment: @code_fodder A console version of this code ran with no problems, but this GUI version crashed. At first glance, I guessed it was a serial port issue because of the fact that removing the `connected_port = new QSerialPort` line results in a well-behaved program. However, when this solution was tried in the actual code, further flaws were found in parent-child widget's relationship, so I may agree with you.  But, on the other side, don't sound odd this program to crash this way?

Comment: When adding Qt modules it sometimes helps to completely delete the build directory and build the project from scratch. You were likely hitting binary incompatibility with your own code. OTOH, you can simply hold `QSerialPort` and the Ui by value in your widget, no need to add indirection via a pointer: `class MainWindow : public QMainWindow { Ui::MainWindow ui; QSerialPort m_serialPort; ... };`